# phonegap build > html5 video on android

Tags: android, html, cordova, video

i am working on a simple responsive html5 project what have to work in browsers AND as a phonegap app on ios and android.

i have issues with the video playback - i did it realy vanilla just with the html5 video tag ...

```
<video controls preload="none" poster="media/video.jpg">
<source src="media/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

what works everywhere : on desktop, in every browser - even on the android tablet itself - but AFTER build with phonegam - the video is just a black window . if i delete the video - i can not press play - but when the video is there i can press play. the player shows no video - and have a wrong duration.

i tryed to fix it with

```
<gap:plugin name="com.dawsonloudon.videoplayer" version="1.0.0" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.8" />
<gap:plugin name="com.jaeger.html5video" version="1.2.1" />
```

but i guess i did this wrong - i have no experience adding plugings the right way / what i have to do then in my app / some scripts...  i dont wana mess up the desktop version :/

any ideas how i should progress to get it run ?

Comment: having the same issue, any updates?